# Omnet++ : Is it possible to recall a parameter as value inside a parameter setting inside the omnetpp.ini?

Tags: config, simulation, omnet++

I'm new on omnet++ and I'm trying to test some simulations but I need to set a parameter according to another parameter.

```
[General]
network = Floor

[Config Test]

Floor.sizeX = ${200, 1000}
Floor.sizeY = ${200, 1000}


Floor.slotTime = 100ms
Floor.radius = ${20, 120}
Floor.PosX = intuniform(0,Floor.sizeX)
Floor.PosY = intuniform(0,Floor.sizeY)


Floor.P = ${0.1, 0.9}

Floor.numberOfNodes = ${20, 500}
```

As you can see, in the .ini file I need to set as value of the "intuniform" the value of the parameter above. But the simulator shows me this error message:

> **Cannot evaluate parameter 'posX': Cannot evaluate parameter 'PosX': (omnetpp::cModule)Floor: Expression cannot be interpreted on network
>   level -- in module (Node) Floor.node[0] (id=2), during network setup**

Moreover I wanted to leave the kind of distribution there, in such a way that I can change it easly. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by _leaving_ _the_ _kind_ _of_ _distribution_?

Comment: I meant, setting the kind of distribution on the .ini file and not on the NED.

Comment: But setting the kind of distribution **is** in omnetpp.ini (i.e. the line `Floor.PosX = intuniform(0, ${X})` is in omnetpp.ini).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to [reference to another parameter value](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-sim:referencing-other-iteration-variables). One has to introduce a variable, for example `X` and reference to it writing `${X}`:

```
Floor.sizeX = ${X=200, 1000}
Floor.sizeY = ${Y=200, 1000}
...
Floor.PosX = intuniform(0, ${X})
Floor.PosY = intuniform(0, ${Y})
```